# differences between creating the regular expressions

Tags: javascript

What are the difference between the following:

```
var myConstructedRegExp = new RegExp("the", "g");
var myLiteralRegExp = /the/g;
```

Are they both method same but only difference is object and primitive references?

Comment: The latter is the so called expression literal, but they're both `RegExp` objects.

Comment: One is a *constructor* and the other one is a *literal*. Both return exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are objects. There isn't a regex primitive.

Some differences are the string version allows more flexibility with crafting the regex, e.g. joining with other strings. Keep in mind you will need to double escape any regex meta characters that you plan on escaping.

Comment: @CasperFlow How would a regex ever be a primitive? Are you confusing primitive with literal?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will want to create a regexp programmatically. In this circumstance, you will need to use `new RegExp`.

Here's ane example

```
var str = "foo";
var re  = new RegExp(str, "g");
//=> /foo/g
```

Using the RegExp literal would not work in this case

```
// does not work!
var str = "foo";
var re = /str/g;
//=> /str/g
```

---

I use the RegExp literal syntax (`/foo/`) for almost all things, but it's good to know you can fall back to the constructor (`new RegExp("foo")`) when needed.

Either way, both regexp creation methods result in an object with equal capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Although functionally the same, there are some slight differences

1. Since the /regx/ notation is a literal you cannot create it dynamically. /abc/ + variable + /def/ does not work. Have to go with constructor notation.
2. Forward slashes have to be escaped in /regx/ notation. Not in constructor.